# Como obter html renderizado de uma ActionResult no Controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Estou realizando uma exportação de PDF onde o conteúdo do documento é o html de uma View Renderizada.

Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu usei a solução desta outra [questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/how-to-render-an-asp-net-mvc-view-as-a-string)(em inglês):

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
  ViewData.Model = model;
  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                             viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                 ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
}


public ActionResult RenderViewToString()
{
    var model = new MeuModelo()
    {
        Nome = "William John",
        Endereco = "123, rue des Canadiens",
        Telefone = "(555) 555-7777"
    };

    string html = RenderViewToString(
            "~/views/Etiqueta.cshtml",
            model);


    CreatePdf(html);

    return View();
}
```

Como funciona:

1. O Método ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView (caso você queira renderizar uma View, use o método FindView) cria uma instância da sua partialview em viewResult
2. uma instância de ViewContext é criada. É nesse ponto que é fornecido o modelo e o tempdata à View.
3. O método Render faz a renderização em HTML e usa o StringWriter para criar um String Builder que vai receber o resultado da Renderização.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado Willian :)  Eu tinha visto esse, mas não estava conseguindo, aparentemente o erro estava na viewname, estava colocando apenas o nome da view e não caminho.